# Get list of dictionaries based on their key values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several dictionaries, let's say 5:

```
dict1={'Age': 20, 'Name': 'Bob'}
dict2={'Age': 10, 'Name': 'Ane'}
dict3={'Age': 40, 'Name': 'Lee'}
dict4={'Age': 50, 'Name': 'Rob'}
dict5={'Age': 30, 'Name': 'Sia'}
```

and

```
arr=[50,40,30,20,10]
```

Can I get a list of dictionaries based on the values of age in `arr`?

Desired output:

```
[dict4,dict3,dict5,dict1,dict2]
```

Comment: What kind of structure are these dicts in? Their own objects? In some kind of list?

Comment: Each dictionary is an imported yml file

Comment: Can be in `arr` different values (that means, not in any dict) or missing values?

Comment: arr is independent but has all possible values

Answer (score 4):

Try using a `lambda` to sort by a certain property (in this case, `Age`):

Code:

```
dict1={'Age': 20, 'Name': 'Bob'}
dict2={'Age': 10, 'Name': 'Ane'}
dict3={'Age': 40, 'Name': 'Lee'}
dict4={'Age': 50, 'Name': 'Rob'}
dict5={'Age': 30, 'Name': 'Sia'}

dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5]

dicts.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x['Age'])

print(dicts)
```

Output:

```
[{'Age': 50, 'Name': 'Rob'}, {'Age': 40, 'Name': 'Lee'}, {'Age': 30, 'Name': 'Sia'}, {'Age': 20, 'Name': 'Bob'}, {'Age': 10, 'Name': 'Ane'}]
```

Comment: boom.. paving a shortcut through a long road ahead. I like it.

Comment: Your solution will work only for sorted `arr`

Comment: @Gabio right, but based on the question above, I don't see any indication that a solution would need to support a non-sorted `arr`.

Comment: Maybe, but this assumption can be avoided. Another issue with the suggested solution - the expected output mentioned by the OP is the dictionaries names and not the value.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments:

```py
arr = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]

dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5]

dicts = {d["Age"]: d for d in dicts}
dicts = [dicts[v] for v in arr]
print(dicts)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"Age": 50, "Name": "Rob"},
    {"Age": 40, "Name": "Lee"},
    {"Age": 30, "Name": "Sia"},
    {"Age": 20, "Name": "Bob"},
    {"Age": 10, "Name": "Ane"},
]
```

Comment: What if arr was composed of random strings instead of values?

Comment: @TYSH Can you edit your question and put there an example (with expected output)?

Answer (score 2):

If the expected output is the dict names and not the values, you can create a mapping between `Age` and the dict name and iterate through `arr` and get the name of the dict by its age:

```
dict1 = {'Age': 20, 'Name': 'Bob'}
dict2 = {'Age': 10, 'Name': 'Ane'}
dict3 = {'Age': 40, 'Name': 'Lee'}
dict4 = {'Age': 50, 'Name': 'Rob'}
dict5 = {'Age': 30, 'Name': 'Sia'}

arr = [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]

age_to_dict_name = {globals()[x]['Age']: x for x in globals() if x.startswith("dict")}
expected_output = [age_to_dict_name[x] for x in arr]
print(expected_output)  # ['dict4', 'dict3', 'dict5', 'dict1', 'dict2']
```